# numba RuntimeError: No available targets are compatible with triple "arm-unknown-linux-gnu"

Tags: raspberry-pi, llvm, numba, llvmlite

I am running a Python application on a Raspberry Pi (Model 4B - 8GB) and I am getting a runtime error. I had a lot of trouble even getting numba to run in the first place, because the available binary distribution of LLVM was too old (version 11), so I had to build LLVM v14.0.0 from source. I am now able to run my application, but I'm getting a runtime error that no available targets are compatible with triple "arm-unknown-linux-gnu", but when I run `llvm-config --targets-built` I get `AArch64 AMDGPU ARM AVR BPF Hexagon Lanai Mips MSP430 NVPTX PowerPC RISCV Sparc SystemZ VE WebAssembly X86 XCore`, so it looks like it was built properly and should have the necessary targets?

Here is the traceback for my issue:

```
(.venv) user@raspberrypi:~/Documents/myapp $ python app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Documents/myapp/app.py", line 31, in <module>
    import MyClass as myclass
  File "/home/user/Documents/myapp/myclass.py", line 17, in <module>
    from model.utils import myfilter
  File "/home/user/Documents/myapp/model/utils.py", line 94, in <module>
    @njit
     ^^^^
  File "/home/user/Documents/myapp/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numba/core/decorators.py", line 287, in njit
    return jit(*args, **kws)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/Documents/myapp/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numba/core/decorators.py", line 201, in jit
    return wrapper(pyfunc)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/Documents/myapp/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numba/core/decorators.py", line 230, in wrapper
    disp = dispatcher(py_func=func, locals=locals,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/Documents/myapp/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 824, in __init__
    self.targetctx = self.targetdescr.target_context
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/Documents/myapp/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numba/core/registry.py", line 48, in target_context
    return self._toplevel_target_context
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/functools.py", line 1001, in __get__
    val = self.func(instance)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/Documents/myapp/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numba/core/registry.py", line 32, in _toplevel_target_context
    return cpu.CPUContext(self.typing_context, self._target_name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/Documents/myapp/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numba/core/cpu.py", line 42, in __init__
    super().__init__(typingctx, target)
  File "/home/user/Documents/myapp/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numba/core/base.py", line 254, in __init__
    self.init()
  File "/home/user/Documents/myapp/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_lock.py", line 35, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/Documents/myapp/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numba/core/cpu.py", line 51, in init
    self._internal_codegen = codegen.JITCPUCodegen("numba.exec")
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/Documents/myapp/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numba/core/codegen.py", line 1171, in __init__
    self._init(self._llvm_module)
  File "/home/user/Documents/myapp/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numba/core/codegen.py", line 1176, in _init
    target = ll.Target.from_triple(ll.get_process_triple())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/Documents/myapp/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/llvmlite/binding/targets.py", line 197, in from_triple
    raise RuntimeError(str(outerr))
RuntimeError: No available targets are compatible with triple "arm-unknown-linux-gnu"
(.venv) user@raspberrypi:~/Documents/myapp $
```

I also opened a GitHub issue here:
https://github.com/numba/llvmlite/issues/975

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work! I followed similar steps to what was suggested in a related issue: https://github.com/numba/llvmlite/issues/497
I think that LLVM was getting built for a 64 bit architecture, even though the Raspberry Pi OS is a 32-bit OS, so I just had to update the cmake parameters to generate build files for a 32 bit version. Then I rebuilt it, reinstalled it, and reinstalled numba and llvmlite and it worked! Here are the cmake parameters that I ended up using that worked:

```
cmake -DLLVM_DEFAULT_TARGET_TRIPLE=armv7l-linux-gnueabihf \
      -DLLVM_TARGET_ARCH=ARM \
      -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=ARM \
      -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
      -DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=On \
      ../llvm
```

Answer (score 0):

Update numpa can simply solve this error:

> pip install -U numba

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).